# Capturing Email activity via AMPScript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Is there any function of AMPScript to be included in a link, or in a Button (in an email), to update a Data Extension every time this button is clicked in the email?

I want to record every time a customer clicks in an email button.

I know that I could automate it vía Query activity, using _Click Data view, but is it possible to do it instantaneously?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, as AMPscript is executed at email send time, there is no way to do so.

Using an automation or triggering the change from your website would be the only options.