# Email embdedded question options

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript

There's an option to use MC's internal Survey function in Classic Content for Emails.

This isn't really good to use as there is no way to store the customer answers to a separate Data Extension. 
I am aware that we can query the Email response results and populate a DE with those, but I'm looking for a more streamlined way.

Based on [Capturing Email activity via AMPScript](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/187081/capturing-email-activity-via-ampscript) question, this is not possible via AMPscript.

I'm assuming same applies for SSJS.

So without the use of landing page, is there a way to have embedded question in an Email, where the answer(s) will be stored to MC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have cloud pages and do not depend on a specific link target outside the marketing cloud you could setup a landing page with a smart capture forum for this. How the scenario works in general:

1. The Marketing Cloud landing page would contain a hidden smart capture form that submits on page load via Javascript.
2. The form is connected to the data extension you want to use for storage of the replies.
3. The different answers to the question in your email are basically buttons with a URL that contains identifying parameters. If you need those tied to the subscriber you should consider options to mask critical subscriber information for data security (don't use a plain email address).

The advantage of this approach is that you may even use the form to trigger follow up communication as triggered email or journey builder entry.

I hope this helps but I'm no web developer and type in my smartphone, so please excuse the lack of technical detail and reference. :)